# How do you find a conjecture for a recursive sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

If you have a sequence that is defined recursively by $U_1=1$ and $U_n=U_{n-1} + (2n + 1)$, with $n>1$, how do you write a conjecture for a formula of $U_n$ in terms of only $n$ (a non-recursive definition)?

The first four terms which I calculated are as follows:
$U_1=1$, $U_2=4$, $U_3=9$, $U_4=16$

I always get stuck when the question asks for creating a formula- I never know where to start. Are there steps you can follow?

Thank you SO much!

Comment: If $U_1=1$, how do you get $U_2=3$?  I think that if you compute the first few terms correctly the pattern will become obvious to you.

Comment: Oops, sorry! On my paper I copied down 2(n-1) instead of (2n-1). I'll fix it now.

Comment: Did you mean to write $U_n=U_{n-1}+(2n-1)$?

Comment: @lulu Op  left out $U_n=$ to the left of the expression written, and should have restricted $n$ by $n \ge 1$ rather than $n>1.$

Comment: Post edit:  is the pattern clear to you now?

Comment: @coffeemath  prior to the edit, the OP had even differences, where odd was clearly called for.  Fixed now.

Comment: @lulu Yes, thank you! They're all perfect squares right? So I could say that the formula for $U_n$ is $n^2$?

Comment: Absolutely.  Though now you have to prove it.  This should not be hard....it's always easier to prove that a solution works than it is to find the solution in the first place.

Comment: You should edit your question to be aligned with the correction that naturally comes from José's comment.

Comment: When trying to prove such a conjecture, my first try is generally induction.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yup! Thank you :)